# miniconda Dockerfile best practices

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, conda, miniconda

I am new to Dockerfile...  I noticed that in some implementation of Dockerfile, people execute a bash script in Dockerfile to install the dependencies (e.g. install_deepchem_conda.sh):

https://github.com/deepchem/deepchem/blob/master/Dockerfile

The problem is that, when I tried to "run" a Docker debugging configuration in pycharm, the environment will re-install the library every single time.  The re-installation really wasted a lot of time.

Questions:

1. What is the Dockerfile best practices when it comes to creating a miniconda environment?
2. With the example above, would it be better to flatten out the bash script, and RUN a set of "conda install -y -q -c  xxx" instead?

Thanks!